# Cookie based redirection

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I've got a multi-page form, 9 stages.  The forms all send a simple e-mail when they're submitted and move to the next stage.  Delivery drivers are going to use it to enter information from their trips.  I've been tasked with having the site its on remember which stage of the form the user was on last, to prevent redundant data entry as much as possible.  I've decided cookies is probably the way to do this, and I've got it to set a cookie every time a stage of the form is set, and when you start it, the 'stage' cookie is set to '1' and goes up numerically every stage until it gets to the last one, and is reset to zero when the last form is submitted.

That all works, and I've got a splash page that will open first.  How do I have it check for the cookie, read the value, and then redirect to the appropriate stage in the form based on the cookie value?

I have a hidden input in every form that passes the value to the cookie.

```
<input id="stage" name="stage" type="hidden" value="3">
```

setCookie function

```
 var today = new Date();
        var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

        function setCookie(name, id) {
            var element = document.getElementById(id);
            var elementValue = escape(element.value);

            document.cookie = name + "=" + elementValue + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
            console.log(document.cookie);
        }
```

The onClick in each submit button

```
onClick="setCookie('stage', 'stage');"
```

I'm not certain how to even go about setting up the redirect on the splash page.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to be a bit more specific here, as to what your actual problem is. First of all, do you want to do this in PHP, or on the client side? Depending on which one you chose -do you know how to read the value of your cookie, in either of those scenarios? If not, then go read up on that first of all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really have any background in development, and I'm trying to cut+paste my way through this task.  I would prefer to use javascript, and the cookies are set the way I need them to be.  Basically I need, on load of a site, to check a cookie value, if it says 1, go to 1.php.  If it says 6, go to 6.php.

Comment: Redirecting elsewhere via JavaScript, usually just means assigning a new URL to `location.href`. So, check what your cookie contains, construct the target URL from that (only you know what your URLs actually look like, so far), and … assign it. If you need any further help with that, then you _need_ to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help and patience.